# How can I debug Nautilus crashes?

Tags: ubuntu, logs, debugging, nautilus, crash

Is there a log file I can peruse, or settings somewhere that might give me a clue?

I'm running GNOME nautilus 3.14.3 ("Files") in Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

As a start, you could run it from the terminal and observe its output there.

It's probably necessary to kill the background daemon first.

```
killall nautilus
nautilus
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also usually crash info regarding Nautilus at 
`/var/log/syslog` (Open with Gedit).
And of course at `/var/log/apport.log`